# How to make the url change appropriately for a single page jQuery login, register and forgot password forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, codeigniter, hashtag

I'm doing an application using CodeIgniter, jQuery etc. 
It has a page in which there are 3 forms to login, register and forgot password. All these reside in a single page.

By default the login page (login form) is shown and on clicking 'register', a register form will be shown without reloading. I accomplished this by making different sections in the view for each forms and then used jquery to call that section which makes the register form show and hide the login form and there is this back button which takes me back to login page.

Code of which is :

```
    jQuery('#register-form').click(function () {
            jQuery('.login-form').hide();
            jQuery('.forget-form').show();
        });

        jQuery('#back-btn').click(function () {
            jQuery('.login-form').show();
            jQuery('.forget-form').hide();
        });
```

I would like to know how to make the url behave properly so that I can reach out to each form by just going to its url.

for example, example.com/#register-form would take me directly to my register form, also by clicking the back button, my url should change appropriately just like how the [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) work. Same goes with forgot password.

I tried the jquery-hashchange plugin but just couldn't figure out exactly how.
Can any one tell me the proper way to accomplish this without the help of any plugin? And if a plugin is must, please suggest one.

Comment: use tabs instead hide() and show(), it will work exactly the same you are mentioning about

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a proper option for my case.. can you suggest some otha way ?

Comment: what #register-form actually is, is this html <a>, <input>, <button> or anything else

Comment: @Adnan #register-form is the ID of the form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if I understand you correctly you are looking to dynamically show or hide the correct form based on either a button click or by the URL itself using the hash tag.  And, if possible you would like this without the aid of a plugin.

Assuming that I understand this correctly then the following code may be something along the lines of what you are looking for.  Please note that I did not put all the error handling, etc. in the example but there is enough here I believe to help "kick start" you n the direction you are looking for.

Some initial jquery / javascripting to set everything up.

```
            var urlHref = window.location.href;
        var urlHostName = window.location.hostname;
        var urlPathName = window.location.pathname;
        var urlHashParam = urlHref.split("#");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#hostName").html(urlHostName);
            $("#pathName").html(urlPathName);
            $("#hostHref").html(urlHref);
            $("#hashTag").html(urlHashParam[1]);

            switch(urlHashParam[1]) {
                case "register":
                    manageForms("register");
                    break;
                case "forgot":
                    manageForms("forgot");
                    break;
                default:
                    manageForms("login");
            }

            $('#btnRegister').click(function() {
                manageForms("register");
            });

            $('#btnLogin').click(function() {
                manageForms("login");
            });

            $('#btnForgot').click(function() {
                manageForms("forgot");
            });

        });

        function manageForms(visibleForm) {
            $("#login").hide();
            $("#register").hide();
            $("#forgot").hide();

            $("#" + visibleForm).show();

            if (history.pushState) {
                // only works if the browser supports pushState.
                window.history.pushState("test", "Title", urlPathName + "#" + visibleForm);
            }

        }
```

Basically what we are doing here is getting the different properties of the windows.login so that we can get the values that we are looking for.

We are defaulting to the login form during the switch (as you want that one first if no hash tag is requested in the url or the one that is requested is unknown)

You also asked to dynamically modify the URL (with the new tag if selected from a button click) without reloading the form again.  This is possible in modern browsers but older ones it is not.  This is managed by the

```
                if (history.pushState) {
                // only works if the browser supports pushState.
                window.history.pushState("test", "Title", urlPathName + "#" + visibleForm);
            }
```

Because not all browser support it yet, a quick check is made for support before using the command.

And finally here is the HTML section for this code test.

```
        HREF: <span id="hostHref"></span>
    <br>
    Host Name: <span id="hostName"></span>
    <br>
    Path Name: <span id="pathName"></span>
    <br>
    Hash Tag Parameters: <span id="hashTag"></span>
    <br>

    <hr>
    <input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login">
    <input type="button" id="btnRegister" value="Register for Access">
    <input type="button" id="btnForgot" value="Forgot Password">
    <hr>
    <div id="login">
        This is the Login Section
    </div>
    <div id="register">
        This is the Register Section
    </div>
    <div id="forgot">
        This is the forgot password section
    </div>
```

Hope that at least some of this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that handle all this scenario. Maybe you should take a look at `Sammy.js` (there are more, but I do only know this one).

Sammy let you define routes like `/#something` and whenever your application get to that route, specific code is executed.

http://sammyjs.org/